Passing and retrieving arbitrary data through a C void* from Fortran
I apologise in advance for the very long message.
I am seeking expertise in order to determine if what I am doing is safe/correct, or if alternatives exists.
I have a C library that can hold a user-pointer (void*) to arbitrary C data, so that the user can set and retrieve this pointer through the library and perform appropriate casting back to the original user-defined type in order to access the data.
Imagine the following interface for simplification:
void set_pointer(void* user_ptr);
void* get_pointer();

I want to make a Fortran interface that allows the user to set this void* to arbitrary (C-interoperable) Fortran derived-types through Fortran as well.
The interface to the C code is relatively straight-forward using the iso_c_binding intrinsic module:
interface
    subroutine c_set_pointer(usr_ptr) bind(C, name="set_pointer")
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr), value, intent(in) :: usr_ptr
    end subroutine c_set_pointer
end interface

interface
    function c_get_pointer() result(usr_ptr) bind(C, name="get_pointer")
        use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
        implicit none
        type(c_ptr) :: usr_ptr
    end function c_get_pointer
end interface

Now imagine I have an arbitrary Fortran derived type (C-interoperable):
type, bind(C) :: UserData
    integer :: i
    real :: f
end type UserData

Now, setting the pointer is not so difficult, I guess, using assumed-type and c_loc:
subroutine set_pointer(data)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    type(*), target, intent(in) :: data

    call c_set_pointer(c_loc(data))
end subroutine set_pointer

Note I could use assumed-type directly in the interface of c_set_pointer and bypass the Fortran wrapper, but my goal would also be (if even possible) to make this pure Fortran 2003, and assumed-type is 2018 (I think).
It gets complicated when trying to retrieve the user-pointer as there is no Fortran equivalent to void* (to my knowledge), and the data could be any derived-type:

It could simply return the type(c_ptr) and let the user c_f_pointer it back to the c-interoperable user-defined type (Here UserData, for the example), but that forces the use of iso_c_binding by the user and I would prefer to avoid it.
I do not know any way to inform the retrieval function of the expected user-defined type so that it could do the manipulation described above automatically and directly return a pointer to the user-defined type.
As the user-pointer is an arbitrary derived-type, the retrieval function could return an unlimited polymorphic pointer class(*), pointer, but this cannot be used with c_f_pointer with the type(c_ptr) returned by the C interface.

I did find a way to bypass the last point by associating the C pointer to a "byte array?":
function get_pointer() result(usr_ptr)
    use, intrinsic :: iso_c_binding
    implicit none
    class(*), pointer :: usr_ptr
    type(c_ptr) :: cptr
    character(len=:), pointer :: data

    cptr = c_get_pointer()
    call c_f_pointer(cptr, data) ! This seems to correctly associate the "byte array" to the user-pointer address
    print *, len(data) ! This gives a 0-length character (?)
    print *, c_loc(data) ! This gives the correct memory address of the user-pointer
                         ! But c_loc will fail if "data" is explicitly "len=0",
                         ! but works with "len=:" although len(data) gives 0 (?)
    usr_ptr => data
end function get_pointer

I used Apple clang 15.0.0 (1500.3.9.4) on a Mac M1 to test that code, and it seems to give the expected result, as I was able to correctly access the components of the user-defined type.
It also worked with gfortran 13.2.0 (Still on Mac M1).
implicit none
type(UserData) :: data
type(UserData), pointer :: data_ptr
data = UserData(f = 3.14, i = 42)

call set_pointer(data)
data_ptr => get_pointer()
print *, data_ptr%f ! prints "3.14"
print *, data_ptr%i ! prints "42"

My question(s) is then:

Is that a correct (will it work for every compiler?) and safe way to proceed, and the limitation of c_f_pointer with class(*) can be bypassed that way using pointers?
Can this be made pure Fortran 2003, as mentioned above (replacing the use of type(*)?)
Can this be further extended in order to get rid of the bind(C) limitation on the user-defined type? (Although I don't think so, as that would allow the use of allocatable arrays and such, and the size of such arrays would be lost)
Am I missing anything else?

Thank you for your help.

Your use of call c_f_pointer(cptr, data) is not allowed.

I don't see it is fruitful trying to avoid returning the c_ptr. It is the Fortran equivalent of void *, it is not true that Fortran does not have an equivalent.

@francescalus would it be allowed if I set the character length to 0 (or something else) instead of deferred? It did compile and gave the same result that way too. I expect that as long as I am not doing anything with the data, there doesn't appear to be any harm in carrying the address to the appropriate pointer that way.

@VladimirFГероямслава I agree, what I said was not really correct. I would simply like to hide away the c-interoperability part when possible if it can be avoided. But maybe it wouldn't be such a big deal either, I'm just trying as many options as possible to determine what's best.

If data is a zero length character then you'll instead not be allowed to do c_loc(data). You could have non-zero length, bur then you'll be breaking the rules when you data_ptr => get_pointer().

@francescalus Why would that be breaking the rules?

Because Fortran has much more strict rules than C for the usage of pointers. The type(c_ptr) and c_f_pointer procedure can give the impression that everything is possible much like in C, but it's not. In (very) short, in c_f_pointer(loc(X),Y) X and Y shall have the same type and kind. You may check the rules for c_f_pointer in https://j3-fortran.org/doc/year/23/23-007r1.pdf

Because the dynamic type of get_pointer() is not the same as the (declared) type of data_ptr.

I understand better now, thank you all for your help.

That said I'm not fully convinced that your code violates the standard. Case (iii) is possibly applicable here, as when you use the result of get_pointer() the function has returned and the character variable has gone out of scope. Therefore one could argue that the underlying "storage sequence" is not (no longer) "in use by any other Fortran entity". This is a borderline case, but maybe valid.

I asked on the Fortran discourse forum, and two people who have usually a pretty accurate knowledge of the standard (one is even member of the committee in charge of the standard) tend to agree with the interpretation that makes your code valid.

@PierU, the call to c_f_pointer In the question is not allowed. A corrected call to c_f_pointer will be allowed, but there's more to the question than just that call. The code in the question as a whole is invalid, and that's independent of whether one particular storage sequence is in use by only one Fortran entity.

@francescalus What does make it invalid (apart the typo i that should be ii) ?

@PierU, the deferred type parameter and the illegal pointer assignment statement.

Ah OK you're talking about the question here, and not the one on the forum...

After looking at the comments and diving a little deeper in the standard, I realised that it was probably not worth being so much on the edge of the standard and simply return a type(c_ptr) from get_pointer().
Thanks everyone for your help and knowledge!
